# It is possible that stopRangingBeaconsInRegion stop notifications of a monitored region?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, cllocation

I'm doing a sample project working with `CLLocationManager`.

I call `startMonitoringForRegion`. Then, I start to simulate a beacon with other device and `didEnterRegion` is called.

In the `didEnterRegion`, I call `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` and works fine.

Then, I pause the beacon emitter and `didExitRegion` is called. In the `didExitRegion` I call `stopRangingBeaconsInRegion`.

If I start again the beacon emitter, `didEnterRegion` is not called.

I found this in the Apple documentation:

> stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:
>   Stops the delivery of notifications for the specified beacon region.

It is possible that `stopRangingBeaconsInRegion` stop notifications of a monitored region?

I try the same without the `stopRangingBeaconsInRegion` and works fine.

Thanks

Adding more information:

```
NSUUID *UUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777"];
NSString *identifier = @"MyBeaconRegion";
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:UUID identifier:identifier];
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    NSLog(@"StartRangingBeacons");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didExitRegion");
    [_locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    NSLog(@"StopRangingBeacons");

}

- (void)locationManager:manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
        NSLog(@"Ranging Beacon: %@ and proximity: %f", beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString, beacon.accuracy);
    }
}
```

And some logs:

```
2015-01-13 09:46:30.559 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] didEnterRegion
2015-01-13 09:46:30.561 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] StartRangingBeacons
2015-01-13 09:46:31.579 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.008799
2015-01-13 09:46:32.575 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.011362
2015-01-13 09:46:33.580 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.012814
2015-01-13 09:46:34.580 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.012909
2015-01-13 09:46:35.579 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.012915
2015-01-13 09:46:36.579 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.011501
2015-01-13 09:46:37.576 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.010177
2015-01-13 09:46:38.576 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.013618
2015-01-13 09:46:39.578 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 09:46:40.573 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 09:46:41.578 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 09:46:42.575 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 09:46:43.578 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] didExitRegion
2015-01-13 09:46:43.579 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] StopRangingBeacons
2015-01-13 09:46:43.581 RegionMonitoring[188:5314] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
```

Then, I turn on the beacon and nothing happens.

If I try with this code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didExitRegion");
    //[_locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    //NSLog(@"StopRangingBeacons");
}
```

Works fine:

```
2015-01-13 10:15:45.945 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] didEnterRegion
2015-01-13 10:15:45.947 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] StartRangingBeacons
2015-01-13 10:15:46.960 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.040842
2015-01-13 10:15:47.960 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.040842
2015-01-13 10:15:48.961 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.040842
2015-01-13 10:15:49.958 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.040842
2015-01-13 10:15:50.960 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:15:51.958 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:15:52.960 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:15:53.956 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:15:54.960 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] didExitRegion
2015-01-13 10:15:54.962 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:15:55.955 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:15:56.960 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:15:57.959 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:02.960 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] didEnterRegion
2015-01-13 10:16:02.962 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] StartRangingBeacons
2015-01-13 10:16:02.963 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.040842
2015-01-13 10:16:02.971 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.040842
2015-01-13 10:16:03.979 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.040842
2015-01-13 10:16:04.979 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.036694
2015-01-13 10:16:05.978 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: 0.036051
2015-01-13 10:16:06.977 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:07.977 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:08.974 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:09.977 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:10.973 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:11.977 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] didExitRegion
2015-01-13 10:16:11.978 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:12.974 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
2015-01-13 10:16:13.977 RegionMonitoring[364:11017] Ranging Beacon: 77777777-1717-2727-7777-777777777777 and proximity: -1.000000
```

Comment: How long did you wait after turning off the beacon before turning it back on?

Comment: I tried to turn on just after the didExitRegion and stopRangingBeaconsInRegion logs and also 3-4 minutes after. I have also had the beacon emitting more than 9 minutes unanswered.

Comment: Please show your code so we can evaluate further.  In theory, what you describe should not cause a problem.  If you doubt it, simply remove the call to `stopRangingBeaconsInRegion` -- it should not make a difference.

Comment: @davidgyoung If I don't call stopRangingBeaconsInRegion, will I consume more battery?

Comment: There is not much battery savings if the beacon is not visible.  Continuing to range beacons does not use much battery if the beacon is not visible, and uses absolutely no more battery when the app is in the background.

Comment: To clarify, ranging will use more battery, but only when your app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks correct.  I suspect what is happening is you are simply seeing a delay on a new detection after you stop ranging.  If you wait 15 minutes do you see second region entry event?

Ranging in the foreground absolutely speeds up beacon detections beacause it tells the OS to do as constant Bluetooth scan to look for beacons.  Ranging causes detections to happen within a few seconds.  If not ranging, iOS uses a 15 minute scan cycle to look for beacons, which may be accelerated by bluetooth hardware filters on iPhone 5+.  The hardware filters are not 100% reliable so detections sonetimes are delayed up to 15 minutes anyway.

See here for details: 
http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html

Comment: I tried again. If I turn on the beacon after 10-12 minutes, I see the region entry event again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per [startMonitoringForRegion is not calling didEnterRegion if the app is started within the region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343960/startmonitoringforregion-is-not-calling-didenterregion-if-the-app-is-started-wit), "`didEnterRegion` is a threshold event, fired when a region is entered. Think about it: an event signaling that you're within a region would fire continuously."  Perhaps the reason it is not firing is because when you call `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` you are already in the region and thus `didEnterRegion` doesn't get called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I put logs in the didEnterRegion and the logs were print. I declared the region with the beacon UUID and there wasn't any other beacon with that UUID in the room.

Comment: So the log printed out from didEnterRegion at first, then you call stopRangingBeaconsInRegion, and the logs are not printed out.  And then you call startRangingBeaconsInRegion and the logs are still not being printed out?

Comment: I have not explained well, sorry. 

1. didEnterRegion log and startRangingBeaconsInRegion log. 
2. Logs with the ranged beacon UUID and the accuracy. 
3. Turn off the beacon. 
4. Logs with the ranged beacon UUID and the accuracy=-1.
5. didExitRegion log and stopRangingBeaconsInRegion log.

Then, turn on the beacon and nothing happens.

Comment: Why does stopRangingBeaconsInRegion log?  By calling stopRangingBeaconsInregion you are telling it to no longer care if a beacon is found in that region.  So when you turn on the beacon, nothing fires...

Comment: I call stopRangingBeaconsInRegion because I'm out of the region and to save battery.

Comment: but by not having it on, it won't know that it's in region and to turn it on.  that's the point of having it run continuously...