# How to stop iBeacon scanning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibeacon

i tried with this Code but this delegates are not calling and not stoping the scanning, at one particular condition i need to call some other function.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region

{
NSLog(@"STOP PLEASEEEEEEEE");

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager stopMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

NSLog(@"didExitRegion");
[manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
NSLog(@"StopRangingBeacons");

}
```

am using this code to  start the beaconScanning

```
-(void)loadUIElements
{

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND , 0), ^{
    self.beaconRegionAny = [[AIBBeaconRegionAny alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Any"];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegionAny];    });

}
```

calling this function when start monitoring the beacons

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

{

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It is possible that stopRangingBeaconsInRegion stop notifications of a monitored region?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912025/it-is-possible-that-stoprangingbeaconsinregion-stop-notifications-of-a-monitored)

Comment: Have you had a look here? It seems to be a similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912025/it-is-possible-that-stoprangingbeaconsinregion-stop-notifications-of-a-monitored

Comment: @Lepidopteron Yes but i need that event then only i can move to next step. My concern is when beacon searching time one match will come that time i want to stop scanning , use that data to call another function.

Comment: NSUUID *myUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"11111111111111111111111111111111"];
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:myUUID
                                                                identifier:@"myCompany"];

this UDID is beacon id or our device id or something else

Comment: Not correct UUID Format, this means any random string can't be converted to NSUUID. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: That i know, i Put some sample.i want to search all the beacons.so one particular UUID can't use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the listener from your `monitoredRegions` list using `stopMonitoring(for:)`. Here'a a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423840-stopmonitoring)

Have you tried this?

```
[self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegionAny];
```

Comment: Yes i tried scanning is on going continuously and always going to

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region

Comment: NSUUID *myUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"11111111111111111111111111111111"]; CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:myUUID identifier:@"myCompany"]; this UDID is beacon id or our device id or something else

Answer (score 0):

create a button action and this line of code.

```
@IBAction func launchButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    // Determine action based on button state
    switch (launchButton.currentState) {
    case .Start:
        beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
        launchButton.currentState = .Stop
    case .Stop:
        beaconManager.stopRangingBeacons(in: region)
        launchButton.currentState = .Start
    }
}
```

Try this way, it works

Comment: Can u please give solution in objective c
and these functions want to do automatically in background